# What is the definition of an unused Station?

Tags: ticket-to-ride-europe

In the rules for the European game, the last sentence under "Building a Train Station" states

> A player is never required to build any Stations. For each Station a
>   player has not used, four points are added to his score at the end of
>   the game.

Does this mean that

- four points are added if he does *not build* a train station, or
- the points are added only if he builds the station but does *not use* it for one of his routes, i.e. he may put a station in but then not use a route which the station opens up?

Answer (score 6):

It means for each Station that you don't play, you get four points at the end of the game. The idea is to force you to weigh up the cost (cards, loss of bonus points) against the benefits (completing your route).

It would be a pretty weird rule if it rewarded you for placing Stations, but making sure you don't use them on any route...

Answer (score 6):

An unused station is one you have not put on the board.

For each station still in your supplies at end of game, you get those 4 points. If you've put it on the board, it's been used, even if you don't need it there to complete your tickets.

I base this upon extensive play of TTR:E on daysofwonder.com.